# DateTimeIndexの日時の加算

Tags: python, pandas

DateTimeIndexのすべての日付をずらす（加減算）したいのですが、
どのようにすればよいでしょうか？

例えば、以下の場合でしたら、df1から10日後の、df2を作成することは可能でしょうか？

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data={
        'Value':[ 100, 200, 300 ]
    },
    index=[
        pd.Timestamp('2021/12/01'),
        pd.Timestamp('2021/12/02'),
        pd.Timestamp('2021/12/03')
    ])
print(type(df1.index))
display(df1)

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data={
        'Value':[ 100, 200, 300 ]
    },
    index=[
        pd.Timestamp('2021/12/11'),
        pd.Timestamp('2021/12/12'),
        pd.Timestamp('2021/12/13')
    ])
display(df2)
```

よろしくお願いします。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
df2 = df1.copy()
df2.index = df2.index.shift(freq='10D')
print(df2)

#
            Value
2021-12-11    100
2021-12-12    200
2021-12-13    300
```

Comment: 解決しました。ありがとうございます。